# Algoritmo que nos calcule la suma de los N primeros números pares

Tags: java

Se pide representar el algoritmo que nos calcule la suma de los N primeros números pares. Es decir, si insertamos un 5, nos haga la suma de 6+8+10+12+14.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Problema4 {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
     int numero=0;

         double suma;
         int par=0;
         int impar=0;
         Scanner num;
         num = new Scanner(System.in);

         System.out.println("Ingrese numero:");
        numero = num.nextInt();
         for(int i=0;1<numero; i++ )
         if (numero%2==0)

         {
             par = numero + 2;

                 System.out.println("la suma es:"+par);
             {

         }
         }
         else{
             impar = numero+1;
         System.out.println("la suma es:"+impar);
         }



         }


    }
```

Comment: edita el titulo de la pregunta ademas no explicas que es lo que necesitas se puede intuir pero necesitas ser  claro.

Comment: me queda la duda los primeros 5 números pares no serian 2, 4, 6, 8, 10?? o es a partir del número que ingresan???

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 1):

```
int sumaDePares = 0;

    int hasta = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Ingrese hasta").trim());
    for (int x = 1; x <= hasta; x++) {
        if(x % 2 == 0){
            sumaDePares += x;
        }
    }
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, sumaDePares);
```

Eso es todo, lo que te falto era solo era sumar la 'i' del ciclo for.

Answer (score 0):

Se puede basar en la formula general de la sumatoria, donde la suma de los `n` primeros números esta dada por `(n*(n+1))/2`, de esta forma la suma de los `5` primeros números seria `1+2+3+4+5 = 15` de igual forma `(5*6)/2 = 15`. Ahora si nos piden la suma de los primeros `5` números pares que sería `2+4+6+8+10 = 30` y apoyandonos en algebra tenemos que esto se puede escribir `2*(1+2+3+4+5)`, como vemos lo que esta dentro del parentesis es igual a la formula general, por lo que en código seria algo así

```
double suma = 0;
int par=0;
int impar=0;
Scanner num;
num = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("Ingrese numero:");
numero = num.nextInt();

suma = numero*(numero+1);
```

ahora, y basados en el ejemplo que coloca donde se ingresa el número `5` y se deben de sumar los números `6 + 8 + 10 + 12 + 14 = 50` y usando algebra tenemos que esto es igual a `2*(3 + 4 + 5 + 6 + 7) = 2*25 = 50` por lo que podriamos plantear el siguiente código

```
int suma = 0;
int numero = 0;
int minimo = 0;
int maximo = 0;

Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Ingrese un número");
numero = input.nextInt();

//validamos si el número ingresado es par o impar, y definimos donde iniciamos
if(numero%2 != 0){
   minimo = (numero + 1)/2;
}else{
   minimo = numero/2; // iniciamos en 3
}
//indicamos donde debemos terminar
maximo = minimo + (numero - 1); //terminamos en 7

//sumamos
while(minimo <= maximo){
   suma += minimo;
   minimo++;
}
suma = suma*2;
```